# How to set floating text in EditText?

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-studio-2.3

In my app registration page, edit text here. In this edittext, I want to show floating text. but I try this below code but not working.Anybody please tell about that..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.citrin.popeye.dev.popeye.Registration">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/signupttl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/signupttl1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:text="Sign up to create an account."
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColorHint="#BDBDBD"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_name"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/email"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColorHint="#BDBDBD"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:hint="Email ID"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/nation"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColorHint="#BDBDBD"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_flag"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:hint="Nationality"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/cor"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColorHint="#BDBDBD"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_country"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:hint="Country of Residence"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/pass"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColorHint="#BDBDBD"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_pass"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:hint="Digital Secure Key password"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/signup"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="SIGN UP"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/btn"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:onClick="onSignUpClick"/>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

In Below, i attached the screenshot

[This is above code screenshot in android studio preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xesrd.png)

Comment: have you added the design gradle dependency for the same?

Comment: I did that using this android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout. What is the issue from your end? Which error you are getting?

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-EditText#displaying-floating-label-feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
```

in your build.gradle file

Comment: what is the latest version of support library?

Comment: please check out this link for latest library updates  [android support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed the gradle file dependency please check the design dependency. it's work in my case.

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:xx.x.x'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency in your build.gradle(module:app)

compile 'com.android.support:design:**25.2.0**'

Change **25.2.0** with your support library version

I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this two dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```